# Amazon Keyspace TRUNCATE instruction doesn't work

Tags: amazon-web-services, cassandra, cql, truncate, amazon-keyspaces

On Amazon Keyspaces on AWS I can't truncate my table.. Have you an idea why ? The instruction seems exist on CQL but doesn't work even on CQL editor on MCS.

```
 ...:~/.cassandra$ cqlsh ... ... -u "...." -p "..." --ssl
 
 Connected to Amazon Managed Apache Cassandra Service at ....
 
 [cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.2 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]
 
 Use HELP for help.
 
 ...@cqlsh> TRUNCATE sfd.countries_tbl;
 
 InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query]
 message="Unsupported statement:
 org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.TruncateStatement@f2c4a18"
 
 ...@cqlsh> TRUNCATE TABLE sfd.countries_tbl; InvalidRequest: Error
 from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Unsupported statement:
 org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.TruncateStatement@55cfc2f8"
 
 ...@cqlsh> USE sfd;
 
 ...@cqlsh:sfd> TRUNCATE sfd.countries_tbl;
 
 InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query]
 message="Unsupported statement:
 org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.TruncateStatement@3530b57a"
 
 ...@cqlsh:sfd> TRUNCATE TABLE sfd.countries_tbl; InvalidRequest: Error
 from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Unsupported statement:
 org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.TruncateStatement@4e4c59b"
 
 ...@cqlsh:sfd> TRUNCATE TABLE countries_tbl; InvalidRequest: Error
 from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Unsupported statement:
 org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.TruncateStatement@764173fa"
 
 ...@cqlsh:sfd> TRUNCATE countries_tbl; InvalidRequest: Error from
 server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Unsupported statement:
 org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.TruncateStatement@9a42377"
```

Comment: the command seems to ok. can you run describe table sfd.countries_tbl and post the output?

Comment: MCS == Managed Cassandra Service?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Truncate is not a supported operation in MCS. See what is/is not supported here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mcs/latest/devguide/cassandra-apis.html

Comment: Wow ! Thank you ! It is strange.. Do you know why ? I am working on for 1 week but I have a lot of problems.. I think that I will come back on Apache cassandra by a native way..

Comment: Just remember, MCS is still in preview. So check that link as time goes on.

Answer (score 0):

Kirk has it correct, that list will keep shrinking.

Comment: That's not an answer.